# One-hot-encoding a R list of characters

Tags: r, dataframe, one-hot-encoding

I have the following R dataframe :

```
id    color
001   blue
001   yellow
001   red
002   blue
003   blue
003   yellow
```

What's the general method to one-hot-encode such a dataframe into the following :

```
id    blue    yellow    red
001   1       1         1
002   1       0         0
003   1       0         1
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. You can create a variable for those observations present in data equals to one and then use `pivot_wider()` to reshape the values. As you will get `NA` for classes not present in data, you can replace it with zero using `replace()`. Here the code using `tidyverse` functions:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Code
dfnew <- df %>% mutate(val=1) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = color,values_from=val) %>%
  replace(is.na(.),0)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
     id  blue yellow   red
  <int> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1      1     1
2     2     1      0     0
3     3     1      1     0
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L), color = c("blue", 
"yellow", "red", "blue", "blue", "yellow")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-6L))
```

Comment: Do you need to load `ggplot2,dplyr,readr,purrr,tibble,stringr,forcats`?

Comment: @sindri_baldur Not really, if you feel comfortable I can only add specific packages!

Answer (score 1):

With `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df), id ~ color, fun.aggregate = length)

#     id blue red yellow
# 1: 001    1   1      1
# 2: 002    1   0      0
# 3: 003    1   0      1
```

Same logic with `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyr)
pivot_wider(df, names_from=color, values_from=color, values_fn=length, values_fill=0)

#   id     blue yellow   red
#   <chr> <int>  <int> <int>
# 1 001       1      1     1
# 2 002       1      0     0
# 3 003       1      1     0
```

`Base R`:

```
out <- as.data.frame.matrix(pmin(with(df, table(id, color)), 1))
out$id <- rownames(out)
out
#     blue red yellow  id
# 001    1   1      1 001
# 002    1   0      0 002
# 003    1   0      1 003
```

Reproducible data

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = c("001", "001", "001", "002", "003", "003"), 
  color = c("blue", "yellow", "red", "blue", "blue", "yellow")
)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this in R. It depends on what packages you are using. Most of the modeling packages such as `caret` and `tidymodels` have functions to do this for you.

However, if you aren't using a modeling package the tidyverse has an easy way to do this.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- tribble(
  ~id,    ~color,
  '001',   'blue',
  '001',   'yellow',
  '001',   'red',
  '002',   'blue',
  '003',   'blue',
  '003',   'yellow')

df_onehot <- df %>%
  mutate(value = 1) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = color,values_from = value,values_fill = 0)
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#    id     blue yellow   red
#   <chr> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 001       1      1     1
# 2 002       1      0     0
# 3 003       1      1     0
```

Comment: You could avoid loading `dplyr` and use `df$value <- 1`

Comment: `dplyr` is a dependency of `tidyr` so it's already being imported. I put it there to be specific. Also, mutate makes the process easy to read and keeps it all in one chain.

Comment: I see but at least it won't pollute the namespace `library(tidyr);mutate(iris, test = "bla") # could not find function "mutate"`.